# Efficiently re-arrange a List<Object> after removing X objects

Tags: java

After working on a small database project I've stumbled across an issue. I have a `Student` object who's ID is dependent on the JTable row number *(thus nothing not 'synced' with the `List<Student> students` that I have stored)* .

After removing multiple Student objects I'd notice that the `list.get(int index)` would not be the same as `JTable#getRow(int row)`. After doing a bit of personal work I came up with the following.

---

```
public class ListIDTest {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Object> objects = new ArrayList<>();
    objects.add(new Object("First", 1));
    objects.add(new Object("Second", 2));
    objects.add(new Object("Third", 3));
    String temp = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, 
            "ID", 
            "Remove", 
            JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
    objects.remove(Integer.parseInt(temp) - 1);
    for(Object o : objects){
        System.out.println("Object name: " + o.getName());
        System.out.println("Object ID: " + o.getId());
    }
  }
}
```

---

**Case one:**

> Input: 3
>
> Output: 
>   `Object name: First
>        Object ID: 1
>        Object name: Second
>        Object ID: 2`

**Case two:**

> Input: 2
>
> Output: 
>   `Object name: First
>        Object ID: 1
>        Object name: Third
>        Object ID: 3`

---

The issue in case 2 is that the database will now print the two Students with S. ID 1 & 2, instead of 1 & 3 *(As the list index is)* . I would like to keep the JTable to print S.ID in incremented order and not jump, instead I should re-arrange the list in an efficient manner to now change the List index back to the same as the S.ID in the JTable.

I could obviously declare a new `List<Student> temp` and add the current list to it and then save the collection, however I don't think that's an efficient way to do it if I have say 200-300 Students~. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, when you remove the i'th object from an `ArrayList`, the indices of the objects following the removed object decrease by one.

So if you change your loop to :

```
for(int i=0;i<objects.length;i++){
    Object o = objects.get(i);
    System.out.println("Object name: " + o.getName());
    System.out.println("Object ID: " + i);
}
```

You would get :

> Object name: First
>   Object ID: 0 
>   Object name: Third 
>   Object ID: 1

And if you wish the printed IDs to be 1 and 2, simply print `i+1`.

Comment: Oh wow my bad, forgot about that, rookie's mistake. You're right! Thanks @Eran I'll have to see what's causing my issues then.